# Why doesn't contact adhesive stick well to cured modified silane polymer?

Tags: adhesion

A contact adhesive(dissolved neoprene rubber) sticks well
to rubbery smooth materials like rubber, so why
doesn't contact adhesive stick well to a cured modified silane  polymer (caulk like [hybrifix super 7](https://thecraftsupply.com/wp-content/uploads/technical-data-sheet-hybrifix.pdf))?
Is there any adhesive that can stick to a cured piece of ms polymer?
(besides the ms polymer itself)
Thanks.

EDIT.
Ms polymer caulk does not stick well to all the materials,
so if you bond two objects (different materials) with ms polymer and
after it cured, one of the object gets loose, what type of adhesive can
you use in order to bond the loosen object to the cured ms polymer?
And why doesn't contact cement stick better to ms polymer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the downvotes, but what you may have is a more polar *siloxane* sealer, which would tend to repel "organic" carbon/hydrogen compounds.

The repulsion is similar to fluropolymers such as Teflon.

It may be possible to find a more compatible match for your contact adhesive by finding a sealant polymer with *side groups* that are more chemically matching.